# QT. QLabel perfomance

Tags: c++, performance, qt, widget

In my application I have a file manager similar to the standart windows explorer.

The structure is:

- QScrollArea
- - QWidget
- - - EFile
- - - EFile
- - - EFile

etc...

Each EFile widget contains 5 QLabels. So when the count of files is more than 30 I have a little delay while they are being created. I decided to create only visible files and create hidden on scroll or resize when they become visible. But it's not a solution - the delay remained (although it decreased of course).

The question is how should I modify my application to remove the delay while showing files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you do not compose your custom widget of QLabels. Instead, you overwrite the paint() function and draw the texts/pixmaps with QPainter. It is not as much work as it sounds. There are tons of examples for that in the Qt examples/tutorials.

Comment: Sounds like this is what I was looking for. thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a file explorer you want to implement, you should consider using a `QFileSystemModel` in combination with a `QTreeView` as shown in the example here:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html

This will save you a lot of trouble.